# Triangle find vertex

Tags: geometry

I am trying to program something with mechanics, 3D stuff etc.
I'd like to have a triangle. 2 of 3 vertices are given. Furthermore, I know every distance between the vertices.

I want to find the position(s) of the missing vertex / vertices.
By looking at the picture below it can be clearly seen that there exist two possible solutions.
Solving this on a sheet of paper is easy, but how could I do that in Java / Calculus?
Does anyone know an algorithm to find the vertex / vertices?

[image: Solved on a sheet of paper. Gives 2 points]

First, I'd like to get this working in 2D. Later I will implement a normal for my triangle (3D space then). I would transform that triangle into 2D space so that I could use the algorithm I am looking for. Does anyone know a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve equation system. To make equations simpler, let's point A is zero.

```
C.X^2 + C.Y^2 = RA^2
(C.X-B.X)^2 + (C.Y-B.Y)^2 = RB^2
```

find unknowns C.X and C.Y and in the end shift them by A.X and A.Y

In 3D you need additional information, because intersection of two spheres is circumference (infinite number of points)

Comment: Thank you :) That equation helped me